# Average over a 3x3x3 voxel in a 192x192x24 volume

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, voxel

I am processing image files with measured intensity, basically extracting voxels in sizes of 1x1x1 pixels. The image files are forming a volume to avoid peak intensities. I would like find a way to average over 3x3x3 pixel.

My problem is to get my head around the problem, because it is a shape within the image separated by zeros and other values. So, first of I considered a `for`-loop with a `if`-statement. These are the considerations I have made so far for the `for`-loop and `if`-statement. MATLAB perceives the volume as a long matrix so by a simple `for` loop it should be easy to find a non-zero value and its adjacent values, and take the average over those values. The problem comes when I have to take the z dimension into account.

This is clearly not working optimal, and I find it hard to account for the boundary effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope I'm interpreting your question right, but you want to find the average over a 3 x 3 x 3 voxel volume for each voxel in the input image where each input voxel acts as the centre of each 3 x 3 x 3 voxel volume to be averaged.  If you have the option of using MATLAB's built-in functions, consider using N-D convolution with [`convn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html).  Don't use loops here because it will be notoriously slow.  For `convn`, the first parameter is the 3D image, and the second parameter is a 3 x 3 x 3 kernel with values all equal to 1/27.  You also have the option of specifying what happens along the border should your convolution kernel go beyond the limits of the input image.  Usually, you want to return an output image that's the same size as the input and so you may want to specify the `'same'` flag as the third optional parameter.  This averaging mechanism also assumes that the outer edges are zero-padded.

Therefore, supposing your image is stored in `im`, do something like this:

```
%// Create kernel of all 1/27 in a 3 x 3 x 3 matrix
kernel = ones(3,3,3);
kernel = kernel / numel(kernel);

%// Perform N-D convolution
out = convn(double(im), kernel, 'same'); %// Cast to double for precision

out = cast(out, class(im)); %// Recast back to original data type
```

---

Alternatively, if you have access to the image processing toolbox, use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) instead.  The difference with this and `convn` is that `imfilter` was written using [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IIPP)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp), and so performance will definitely be faster:

```
%// Create kernel of all 1/27 in a 3 x 3 x 3 matrix
kernel = ones(3,3,3);
kernel = kernel / numel(kernel);

%// Perform N-D convolution
out = imfilter(im, kernel);
```

The added bonus is that you aren't required to change the input type.  `imfilter` automatically infers this, does the processing respecting the input image's original type and the output type of `imfilter` is the same as the input type.  With `convn`, you must ensure that your data is floating-point before using it.